# SQL Server: unable to add constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraints, case, between

I am trying to create a table and category the price based on the follow criteria:

- For category 1, the range of values is 7 to 20, inclusive.
- For category 2, the range of values is 20 to 50, inclusive.
- For category 3, the range of values is 50 to 100, inclusive.
- For any other category, the range of values is 100 to 350, inclusive.

But I kept hitting error

```
CREATE TABLE LabTest
(
    testCode char(4) not null,
    name char(40) not null,
    category int not null,
    price decimal(30,2) not null,
    ageAppropriate int not null,

    constraint testCode_PK PRIMARY KEY (testCode),
    constraint age_CHK check (ageAppropriate >= 0),
);

ALTER TABLE LabTest
    ADD CONSTRAINT Category_CHK 
        CHECK (CASE Category
                  WHEN Price BETWEEN 7 AND 20 THEN 1
                  WHEN Price BETWEEN 20 AND 50 THEN 2
                  WHEN Price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 3
                  WHEN Price BETWEEN 100 AND 350 THEN 4
                  ELSE 0    
               END);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to phrase the constraint as come column value being equal to the `CASE` expression:

```
ALTER TABLE LabTest
ADD CONSTRAINT Category_CHK CHECK  
(
    Category = CASE WHEN Price BETWEEN 7 AND 20 THEN 1
                    WHEN Price BETWEEN 20 AND 50 THEN 2
                    WHEN Price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 3
                    WHEN Price BETWEEN 100 AND 350 THEN 4
                    ELSE 0 END
);
```

Side note: The ranges in your `CASE` expression are actually overlapping, because `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both ends.  So, what you wrote would behave the same as this:

```
CASE WHEN Price >= 7 AND Price <= 20 THEN 1
     WHEN Price > 20 AND Price <= 50 THEN 2
     WHEN Price > 50 AND Price <= 100 THEN 3
     WHEN Price > 100 AND Price <= 350 THEN 4
     ELSE 0 END
```

If the above is not how you want to handle the boundary conditions, then change the logic as you want.

Comment: Thanks!!, the code is working. Let say, instead of checking, i want to return the input the value back to category column. Can it be done?

Comment: You're asking a different question now, but if I understand correctly, then a computed column might be what you want.  You can make `Category` computed based on the `Price`.